# PHP sql statement that fails in a script but works on a production server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website and I have tested this sql statement on the production server and it works, no errors and returns the correct results. But when I execute it via php, it tells me I have an error.

```
$query = "SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    select r.id, r.name from recipes r inner join fav5 f on r.id=f.recipeid where   f.memberid='$id'";
```

This is the error when used in a php script:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select r.id, r.name from recipes r inner join fav5 f on r.id=f.recipeid where f.' at line 2

What the heck is going on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant use delimiters (;) in sql from php

It's a security issue, one line at a time.

Comment: I guess I cant accept an answer in 8 min according to Stack Overflow, but I just tried it and it worked! You are the best!!!! I'll accept it as an answer when it lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `mysql_query()` to execute the SQL. If that's the case, that function does not support multi-queries.

You'll need to use [mysqli_multi_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: FYI, many servers don't have the mysqli extension installed with php. If you can't get that to work, that's probably the problem.